# How to read an attachment content into an array or String by clicking a button on XPage?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, xpages

I have an XPage with an File Upload/Download control that shows my attachments. I need to read a content of ***first*** file attachment (name not known/random) into a string var or array by clicking a button.

I am not sure if XMLHttpRequests() can work on XPage or if there is an standard XPages control to do that?

I do need just to read content. (Users don't need to interact with attachment directly (select/save/other UI actions)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example:

```
importPackage(java.net);
importPackage(java.io);

var valString:String = "";
var nrt:NotesRichTextItem=document1.getDocument().getFirstItem('Body');

if (nrt!=null){
    var eos:java.util.Vector = nrt.getEmbeddedObjects();
    if (!eos.isEmpty()) {
        var eo:NotesEmbeddedObject = eos.get(0);
        var inputReader:BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(eo.getInputStream(), "UTF-16"));
        while ((inputLine = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            valString+=inputLine + "<br>";
        }
        if (inputReader != null){inputReader.close();}
        eo.recycle();
    }
}

return valString;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to clarify what "first" means: oldest, attached first, first in alphabet? Domino doesn't guarantee a sequence. You can use `@AttachmentNames` in an evaluate statement. You then get use that name to directly access that attachment from your browser using a rest call using this syntax:

`http(s)://[yourserver]/[application.nsf]/[viewname|0]/[UNID| ViewKey]/$File/[AttachmentName]?Open`

More details are in [this blog entry](http://notessensei.com/blog/2010/06/attachment-urls-in-xpages.html).

If you want to handle that on the server side then you use document.[getAttachment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETATTACHMENT_METHOD_JAVA.html?lang=en)().

Comment: Well, let's suppose the document has just one attachment the name I don't know. By clicking on a button I want to read entire content of that attachment into e.g. scopeVariable or array

Comment: document.getEmbeddedObjects gives you the Attachments, in EmbeddedObjects there's a stream method to get the content